# Grouping multiple Divs into one div

Tags: css, grouping

I'm not sure how, or if this is possible, nor do I know the proper terminology in order to properly search for this. I assume it's an easy question.

I have a logo that I made, using some images and some CSS. The image is comprised of several layers, each of which is it's own layer.

My code is similar to this:

```
.logo .layer1 {
}
.logo .layer2 {
}
.logo .layer3 {
}
.logo .layer4 {
}
```

It works fine, when I call each div like so:

```
<div class="layer1">
<div class="layer2">
<div class="layer3">
<div class="layer4">
```

But my question is, how/if possible, can I simply call:

```
<div class="logo">
```

When I do this, nothing shows up.

Comment: What do you mean "call"?

Comment: Setting the <div> in html. When I add <div class=""> This is what I mean when I "Call" something.

Comment: You call <div class="logo"> with ".logo"

Comment: But it doesn't call any of the .logo .layers

Comment: Well, them you can call by .logo .layerX? The question is really hard to understand. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your HTML to:

```
<div class="logo">
  <div class="layer1"></div>
  <div class="layer2"></div>
  <div class="layer3"></div>
  <div class="layer4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, I have to have each individual layer listed? I can't simply call '<div class="logo">' and have it automatically call the individual layers associated to it?

Comment: They div's should created in the HTML, so the browser knows they should be displayed. The css won't create any div's for you in the HTML code.

Comment: @level42 You can just have four divs all with class="logo", if that's what you mean.

Comment: Thanks ZeroRequiem, this is all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Create HTML first,

```
<div class="logo">
  <div class="layer1"></div>
  <div class="layer2"></div>
  <div class="layer3"></div>
  <div class="layer4"></div>
</div>
```

Now you can use css to target the elements:

```
.logo .layer1 {
  background: url('something.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}
.logo .layer2 {
  background: url('something.jpg') top right no-repeat;
}
.logo .layer3 {
  background: url('something.jpg') bottom left no-repeat;
}
.logo .layer4 {
  background: url('something.jpg') bottom right no-repeat;
}
```

e.g. .logo .layer4 calls the descendant class .layer4 of .logo